# why did remix give a NOT FOUND error for @chainlink/contracts

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Why did remix give a `NOT FOUND` error?

(I knew `safemath` is not necessary since v0.8.)

code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }
    
    // 1000000000
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
        
        for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
}
```

Errror: not found "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol"

I use  same code FundMe.sol via Patrick Collins github lesson3
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNors.png)

Comment: Can you tag this with Chainlink, add the text of the error you’ve run into, and the text of the code you’re using to get this?

Comment: i fixed tag and ı added picture and note

Comment: Please don't just use the picture, we need the text so others who run into this can search for it and web crawlers will index it.

Comment: Relax my Master :) i fixed it

Comment: Great, could you refresh remix? I've just tested the code, it looks correct. Then Hit the `compile` button.

Comment: yeahh Patrick it was okay.Thanks  i changed version and refreshed.DONE :)

Answer (score 1):

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

COMPILER

0.6.6+commit.6c089d02

Answer (score 1):

Simple Suggestion:
create a new contract file undername "SafeMathChainlink.sol and given code below in contract folder,
and put a code import "./SafeMathChainlink.sol" in FundMe.sol instead of giving chainlink;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you came here following the "**Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial**" course by **Patrick Collins**; here's what you need to change to make this work:

If you get this error:

```
ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Make sure:

- You use `pragma solidity ^0.6.0;` (or similar; i.e.: `pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;`) at the top of your contract,
- Select a compiler version that fits what the AggregatorV3Interface.sol interface is expecting (`pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`)
- And hit re-compile :)